# How to match string in query file in Hyperledger Composer?

Tags: javascript, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am facing one problem in this query statement: Query is returning no results.

query:

```
statement:
      SELECT org.example.identitynetwork.IdentityProof
          WHERE ((owner == _$owner) AND (proofName == _$proofName))
```

my cto is:

```
asset IdentityProof identified by proofId {
  o String proofId
  o String proofName
  o String encodedData
  --> Owner owner
}
```

In logic.js:

```
let idProofs = await query('selectRequestedIdProofsByOwner',
    {
        "owner": proofOwner,
        "proofName": proofName
    }
);
```

This query is returning no results even if I have permissions configured properly and there exists a proof with the given owner and proof name.

Comment: Got relationship matching working !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `where` and `and` filters,

```
let idProofs = await query('selectRequestedIdProofsByOwner',
    {
        "where": {
            "and": [
                { "owner": proofOwner },
                { "proofName": proofName }
            ]
        }
    }
);
```

Point to be noted, This does not work with relationship attributes, This is just for basic string matching. In your example `owner` matching with `proofOwner` won't work.

### Update

Relationship matching can be done by prefixing `namespace` name with `Resource type` followed by `#` and `Unique` resource id.

```
let idProofs = await query('selectRequestedIdProofsByOwner',
    {
        "where": {
            "and": [
                { "owner": "resource:org.example.businessnetwoek.ParticipantType#"+proofOwner },
                { "proofName": proofName }
            ]
        }
    }
);
```

In your example `uniqueId` will be `proofOwner`

Comment: Then how to match relationships?

Comment: Didn't figured it out yet :)